# Firestore check cache first

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to check if the documents from Firestore have been cached locally?

Basically on first loading the app will connect to Firestore to download all documents.

Once this is done, on future opening, I will connect Firestore to check 'update timestamp', if this is set to same as the app locally stored timestamp then I only want the app to get cache documents.

In order to achieve this I need to check if cache documents exists.

Is there a way to do this?

Tried:

```
appDelegate.db.collection("Calculators").getDocuments(source: .cache) { [self](querySnapshot, error) in
            if querySnapshot == nil { // if here then cache exists
```

Issue with this is that due to asynchronous nature...it takes time to get the result.

So I'm looking for a way to check locally if cached documents exist, not via snapshot

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the problem. Reading documents is an async operation, there's no other way within the API. If you want something synchronous, you could do your own synchronous storage instead - byt you'd have to write that yourself.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I want to see if cache version of the firestore documents exist. Able to do this with code above, but as it's async it takes time and the rest of the code goes ahead. Was looking for a way to check if cache exist in synchronous manner

Comment: Appreciate if not possible, without having to do own synchronous storage

Comment: What is the ultimate goal here? To save money by only reading from the cache if the cache is up to date with the server?

Comment: @trndjc absolutely. Exactly that

Comment: I assume there would only be one global timestamp that the client cares about? And so if data in any one document changes, then this timestamp is updated and the clients go to the server?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that.

Comment: The first problem I see is that you cannot guarantee which documents the client will have in its cache. For instance, whatever documents are read by the client whenever the app launches will always be in the cache. And from this one may surmise that the client will be up to date with the server on the subsequent launch if the data in the server doesn't change, but what if that client never navigated through the app and never filled up its cache?

Answer (score 0):

Reading documents is an async operation. There's no other way to read or check for the existence of a document synchronously within the API.

If you want something synchronous, you could store some marker in your own synchronous storage instead - but you'd have to write that yourself.